# Find $P(X_{(7)}/X_{(10)} \leq a) $ where $X_{(n)} = \max(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}), x_{i} \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find $P(X_{(7)}/X_{(10)} \leq a) $

where $X_{(n)} = \max(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})$

$x_{i} \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$

I found that $CDF: F_{n} (x) = [F(x)]^n  $

and $pdf: f_{n} (x) = n f(x) [F(x)]^{n-1} $

So I'm thinking of that

$$P(X_{(7)}/X_{(10)} \leq a) = P (X_{(7)} \leq a X_{(10)} \mid X_{(10)} = x)$$

$$=\frac {P(X_{(7)} \leq a X_{(10)}, X_{(10)} = x)}{P(X_{(10)} = x)}$$

$$=\frac {(xa)^7} {10 (x)^9} = \frac {a^7}{10x^2}$$

Does this all make any sense at all? Is this the right direction?

==================

Edit: How does this compare to $$P(x_2/x_3 \leq t)$$ ?

Comment: By $F_n$ you appear to mean the c.d.f. of $X_{(n)}$.  I'd have said that explicitly.

Comment: Just to clarify: if $X_{(7)}$ denotes the sample maximum in a sample of size 7, and $X_{(10)}$ denotes the sample maximum in a sample of size 10, then they are clearly not being drawn from the same sample. So, are you saying you have 2 samples:  one of size $n=10$, and another of size $n=7$?  ORRRR ... do you actually seek the distribution of the ratio of the 7th and 10th order statistics, in a sample of size 10?

Comment: @wolfies Xi - iid U (0,1).  so, yes by definition of $$$x_{(n)}$ it appears that they have different sample size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$, then the pdf of the sample maximum (in a sample of size $n$) is:  $n x^{n-1}$. Thus:

- if $x_{(n)}$ denotes the sample maximum in a sample of size $n$, and
- if we have two independent samples, one of size 10, and the other of size 7,

... then the joint pdf of $(x_{(10)}, x_{(7)})$, say $g(x_{10}, x_{7})$, is simply:

[image]

You seek $P(\frac{x_{(7)}}{x_{(10)}} \le a)$ which is:

[image]

where I am using the `Prob` function from the `mathStatica` package for *Mathematica* to do the pleasantries (I am an author of the former). All done.

---

As an aside, the pdf of your ratio is just the derivative of the cdf above wrt $a$, which yields:

[image]

Here is a plot of the theoretical pdf of $\frac{x_{(7)}}{x_{(10)}}$ (red dotted) and superimposed on top is a Monte Carlo simulation of the same ratio (always a great way to check for mistakes):

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. How does this compare to $$P(x_2/x_3<a)$$ ? note, it's not the order statistic anymore

Comment: @wolfies : Please note that $X$~$N$ looks different from $X\sim N$ (coded as X\sim N).  The latter is standard usage.  (I changed it.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy \simsalabim!  Thanks Michael  -- added to my LaTeX tricks list

Answer (score 1):

The quantity $P(X_{(7)}/X_{(10)}\le a)$ does not depend on any number called $x$, so you should get something not depending on some number called $x$.  And just what $x$ is at that point is not clear.  It is correct that
$$
\Pr\left(\dfrac{X_{(7)}}{X_{(10)}}\le a\right) = \Pr(X_{(7)}\le aX_{(10)}).
$$

If you look at $\displaystyle\Pr\left(X_{(7)}\le aX_{(10)} \mid X_{(10)}=x\right)$, and find that it's some particular number, which let us call $g(x)$, then $\displaystyle\Pr\left(X_{(7)}\le aX_{(10)}\right)$ is actually the expected value of $g(X_{(10)})$.  That can be written as
$$
\Pr\left(X_{(7)}\le aX_{(10)}\right) = \mathbb E\left(\Pr\left(X_{(7)}\le aX_{(10)}\right) \mid X_{(10)}\right).
$$
(Google the term "law of total expectation".) That is actually a somewhat useful way to look at it if you can show that the conditional probability distribution of $X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(9)}$ given the value of $X_{(10)}$ is actually the same as the distribution of the order statistics from a sample of size $9$ on the interval $(0,X_{(10)}$.  But it's even more convenient to look directly at
$$
\frac{X_{(1)}}{X_{(10)}},\ldots,\frac{X_{(9)}}{X_{(10)}}
$$
and show that that has the same distribution as the order statistics from a sample of size $9$ on the interval $(0,1)$.

Maybe I'll add more later.....

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand that I'm wrong, but I have no idea how to move forward. Maybe you could help with simpler example P(x(2)/x(3)<a) ? From what you are saying $$
\frac{X_{(1)}}{X_{(3)}},\frac{X_{(2)}}{X_{(3)}}
$$ has the same distribution as $$ x1, x2$$ and therefore P(x2)/x(3)<a) is $$\frac{a-0}{1-0}^2=a^ 2$$ ?

Comment: Yes.  It's the same as the distribution of the order statistics from a sample of size $2$, and similarly the case addressed in my answer has the same distribution as the order statistics from a sample of size $9$.

Comment: thank you very much fr a simple and elegant solution. the exercise I have says to use conditional probability.. does that mean I need to use a different approach